# Calling an unmanaged c++ function having arguments as pointers from VB.Net

Tags: c++, vb.net, pinvoke

I've the following function written in unmanaged c++, and I'd like to call it from VB.net code. The main problem for me is the function asks for the first argument to be passed as a pointer. And in Visual basic we don't have pointers like c++.

So how can I call this function from vb.net?

```
__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall setup(char *name, int &maxchars)
```

Comment: Impossible to answer with this information. What are the semantics of `name`. Is it an in, out or in/out parameter?

Comment: name is an in parameter. I'm passing the name of the session to be established from VB.NET to c++ Unmanaged dll c++ file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd p/invoke it like this:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
....
<DllImport("MyLib.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
Private Sub setup(ByVal name As String, ByRef maxchars as Integer)
End Sub
```

You need to specify that the character set is `ANSI` since the C code receives `char*`. You don't need to specify the calling convention since the default is `stdcall` which matches the native code.

Comment: This is an unusual interface though. If the string really is an IN parameter, then what is the maxchars parameter used for?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac7ay120.aspx) for the mapping of data types.

```
    Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    Declare Auto Sub setup Lib "xxx.dll"
(ByVal  name as String, ByRef maxchars as Integer)`.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I tried your code and it's not working. 
I only get the first letter in the name string

I was using the following code:
    <DllImport("Chat.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
    Private Shared Sub setup(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)> chatName As Char(), ByRef size As Integer)
    End Sub

Also I'm getting the same result of your code.